# Как в цикле вывести определённое количество чисел?

Tags: javascript, циклы, for

**Задача:**

Написать программу, которая каждую секунду *(максимум секунд - 1000000)* выдает очередное число последовательности 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5... (Т.е. число i повторится i раз).
За 1 секунду считается 1 выведенное программой число, таким образом, на вводе

```
5
```

мы получим ответ

```
12233
```

написал простейший код под такую программу

```
a = parseInt(prompt("Введите кол-во секунд работы генератора"))
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++){
  x = i
  y = x
  for (z = 0; z != y; z++){
  console.log(y)
  }
 }
```

однако при таком коде ответом для

```
5
```

будет являться

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
```

Соответственно вопрос: Каким образом прервать цикл там где мне нужно? Пытался добавлять еще переменные пример:

```
a = parseInt(prompt("Введите кол-во секунд работы генератора"))
c = 0
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++){
  x = i
  y = x
    if (c >= a){
      break
    }
  for (z = 0; z != y; z++){
  console.log(y)
    c += 1
  }
 }
```

, которые считали бы цикл, но код при них перестает работать.

Comment: Добавь код, как пытался добавить. Переставал работать, конечно же, не от переменных, а от того, что неправильно добавил.

Comment: Так-то все элементарно, конечно - во внутреннем цикле считаешь количество выведенных чисел, и как только оно равно нужному числу, завершаешь оба цикла.

Comment: @Эникейщик
 Вот, хотел как раз считать кол-во выведенных чисел во внутреннем цикле, через переменную ```c```, но видимо что-то написал не так (обновил вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

**Решение**

```
a = parseInt(prompt("Введите кол-во секунд работы генератора"))
c = 0
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++){
    if (c >= a){
      break
    }
  for (z = 0; z != i; z++){
  console.log(i)
    c += 1
    if (c >= a){
      break
    }
  }
 }
```

*(Гениально забыл закрыть второй цикл)*

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам нужно аж две лишних переменных `x` и `y`, когда вы можете просто использовать `i` там, где используете `y`, а `x` у вас вообще нигде не используется просто :)

Comment: Где секунды?)))

Comment: @EzioMercer в условиях за секунду выступает одно выводимое в консоль число

Comment: @bruh Бессмысленные секунды какие-то, если честно :) Легче просто сказать, что нужно вывести последовательность чисел длиной `n`, типа `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ....`, где каждое число повторяется столько раз чему он сам равен :)